# Unable to register micro-service on Eureka registry on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, spring-cloud, azure-aks, netflix-eureka

I'm workin on a Spring Cloud micro-services project that I'm deploying to Kubernetes on Azure AKS.

For Discovery part, I'm relying on Eureka within Spring Cloud Netflix project.
To do so, on my local development environment I use this config on every micro-service who need to be registered on Eureka :

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Now when I want to deploy it on Kubernetes I put :

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: https://eureka-server:8761/eureka/
```

But when I go to Eureka dashboard it show that there is no instance :

[image]

I'm suspecting that the `eureka-service` URL is not correctly set to be accessible by other Pods despite it's exposed as a `LoadBalancer` and have its external IP.

Comment: What is the service of `eureka`? Maybe you can try to use the ingress to access the `eureka` service with `ClusterIP` type.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Actually `eureka` service is exposed as `LoadBalancer`. I logged in one of my micro-services and performed a `curl` on eureka and it responded correctly. So I think using an ingress will just expose it publicly.